# Keystroke to clear the current line at the prompt

Tags: bash, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

How can the current line be cleared?  I'm using bash.

I don't like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> because it leaves crap printed on the screen.

If the cursor is at the end of the line I can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and it does exactly what I want.  But if the cursor is mid-line, I need to use a sequence like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) to get the desired behaviour.

Is there one keystroke which does it regardless of where in the line the cursor is positioned?

I also wonder if this is possible in vim (same behaviour as `0D` but with one keypress)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *bash* you can bind the `kill-whole-line` command to e.g. `CTRL-K`

```
bind '"\C-k": kill-whole-line'
```

This does exactly what you want (from `man bash`):

> `kill-whole-line`
>                 Kill all characters on the current line, no matter where point is.

Put this to your `~/.bashrc` if you want this behavior persistent.

If you want to rebind `CTRL-U` you have to include the following line in your `~/.inputrc`

```
set bind-tty-special-chars off
```

see [this bug report](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2006-06/msg00032.html).

---

In *vim* you can define a shortcut for `0D`.

```
map <C-k> 0D
imap <C-k> <ESC>0Di
```

You can test this in command mode (`:`) or put it in your `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc` to make it permanent. Choose a sensible shortcut for your needs, I used `CTRL+K` to be consistent with the bash example. The `imap` line is used in *insert mode*, so you don't even have to go to *command mode* to kill the current line, i.e. this saves two other key presses. (I'm no `vim` crack, so there might be better ways to achieve this, but it seems to work...)

Comment: Thanks, the kill-whole-line binding is perfect!  For vim, of course I know about dd but it does something different to 0D (the latter leaves an empty line, the former kills the newline aswell).

Comment: @wim . My bad, I improved the vim part.

Comment: Just a quick question, if I put `bind C-k:kill-whole-line` in .bashrc and source .bashrc it works, but when I try to use C-u instead it doesn't, the keystroke ctrl+u seems to retain the old behaviour.  Any idea why?

Comment: @wim : I'm puzzled -- I can reproduce the problem with `C-u`, but have no explanation yet. It is even not possible to unbind this function with `bind -u unix-line-discard`...

Comment: @wim : Mystery solved... CTRL-U is a special tty character. See my once again updated answer to get rid of the default binding!

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two keystrokes (dd). First
Set bash to vi mode (which enables vi command editing with the bash command line):

```
set -o vi
```

Then to delete the current line type `dd`.